# How do i use MongoDB to integrate with WIndowsForms using C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms

I would like to ask how MongoDB is able to integrate with Windows Form? I cannot find a way to integrate them together but i was able to print selected documents from my database in MongoDB in console applicaiton which is what i have been following for tutorials online.I dont know how to integrate mongodb with windows form.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between getting data from MongoDB in a console application or in a windows form application using C#, the only difference is how you display your data after getting them from MongoDB.

With console application you use Console.WriteLine() to print out your data, with window form application, you bind your data maybe to a Gridview or just some label.

Comment: What if i would want to present the database as graph in Windows form?(: